# highlight text in input field and have cursor active at the same time - possible?

Tags: javascript, html

I've just been told to do this:

- The user search string should be fully highlighted
- The cursor should be active in the search box

Afaik - this is not possible without some serious hacking - correct?

Comment: What's the purpose of the highlighting?

Comment: @Will, no idea - boss'es request

Comment: I realize you're not asking about UX opinions but... if the purpose is to emphasize the search string, a heading would be better "You search for *Bob LobLaw*". If it's to allow the user to quickly erase it, there's no reason to also have the cursor there as it would immediately erase it on typing. A mobile style [X] on the side would be more natural.

Comment: @Will I agree. this request sounds silly - I just wanted the confirmation that this is not easily achievable thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't even think you can answer it unless you know what it's for. Highlight can mean 'call out' or it might mean 'select'. "The *highlighted* answer" vs "*Highlight* the text with your mouse". You can not have selected text and a cursor within the same input box.

That said, a div with a white background and a grey border can be made to look like an input if the text styles for that div match your input text CSS. Put the div and the input into a wrapper with `position: relative;` set. Position `.fake-input-div` over your actual input via `position: absolute` with a little left side breathing room. Select `.fake-input-div`'s text via JS and focus the input. That left side breathing room should reveal the cursor in the input. `onkeydown` for the input, hide the fake div. Then deal with the other N possible interactions users will be expecting. :)

It's a similar technique a number of the the autocomplete libraries use so that it appears like your selected items are still in the input (say tags in wordpress or friends' names on that blue social network).

Best: explain to your boss why this is a bad idea. :)

Comment: >Best: explain to your boss why this is a bad idea. :).  haha - I just did. Simple focus() is OK he says. But thanks for your response!